# What does cipher.update do in java?

Tags: java, cryptography, aes, des, cbc-mode

I am implementing DES -  CBC. I am confused as to what `cipher.init`, `cipher.update` and `cipher.dofinal` do. I just use init to set the key and `dofinal` to get the result. I don't use update. Is that correct?

Also whats the difference to the result when using *UTF-8* and *ASCII* encodings?

Here is my code:

```
byte[] ciphertext;

Cipher enc = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");   

enc.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(key, "DES"), new IvParameterSpec(vector));

// Is this the complete ciphertext?
ciphertext = encrypt.doFinal(data.getbytes("UTF-8"));
```

Comment: It's `byte`, not `bytes`...

Comment: Did you read the docs on [`Cipher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html)? The javadocs should be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Javadoc for [`Cipher.doFinal(byte[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#doFinal%28byte%5B%5D%29) says (in part with emphasis added),

> Encrypts or decrypts data in a single-part operation, **or finishes a multiple-part operation**. The data is encrypted or decrypted, depending on how this cipher was initialized.
>
> The bytes in the input buffer, and any input bytes that **may have been buffered during a previous update** operation, are processed, with padding (if requested) being applied. If an AEAD mode such as GCM/CCM is being used, the authentication tag is appended in the case of encryption, or verified in the case of decryption. The result is stored in a new buffer.

This is done so you don't have to read all of a file (for example) into memory in order to encrypt it.

Comment: Whats a scenario in which I would need to call update()?

Comment: @dfs I touched on this in my last sentence, if you need to encrypt a large file it's often impractical to read the entire file into a `byte[]` in order to call `doFinal(byte[])` with the entire message at once. Instead you would use `update()` to process the file as you read it in chunks.

Comment: Thank you. I got it now. Do you know what  difference it makes to the result (when I print it to screen) if I use  UTF-8 or ASCII encoding? I will print it in hex

Comment: @dfs That depends on the message.